# Dataframe.head() takes forever

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I imported a JSON-file from Blob Storage, which is around 50GB in size.

```
dsm_temperature_df = spark.read.json(file_location, multiLine=True)
```

After the import into a Databricks spark dataframe, which took around 40 minutes, I want to show the first row with `df.head()`. Unfortunately this takes forever. I let it run for 60 minutes but then I stopped it. I am  Am I doing something wrong here?

PS: I found out that for a smaller json file, which contains around 1GB, it takes over 2 minutes to execute the `df.head()` or `df.first()` methods. For a 50GB json this would mean more than 100 minutes to get the first row. This can't be for real, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the code before. There was a wrong data transformation and therefore the dataframe was broken.